# Given two specific sets, show that one is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

> Given $$X = \{x : x = 4^n-3n-1 ; n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ and $$Y = \{y : y = 9(n-1); n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ Prove that $X \subset Y$.

I've been struggling with this problem for hours but I couldn't find a solution. All I could figure out is that when I put the same value of $n$ in the condition of both sets (as a bound), the elements of set become the same. e.g When I put $n = 1$, I get $X = \{0\}$ and $Y = \{0\}$. But I need a valid proof for it.

Comment: Show that $4^n - 3n - 1$ is divisible by $9$ for all $n$ and Y is the set of multiples of $9$.

Comment: @ZainPatel Thanks you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zain Patel's answer outlines what kind of argument you really to construct: an **induction** argument. The general flow of the inductive proof will be like so:

Fix some $k\geq 1$ and assume that
$$
P(k) : 4^k-3k-1=9\ell\qquad(\ell\in\mathbb{Z})
$$
holds. To be shown is that
$$
P(k+1) : 4^{k+1}-3(k+1)-1=9\eta\qquad(\eta\in\mathbb{Z})
$$
follows. Starting with the right-hand side of $P(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
4^{k+1}-3(k+1)-1 &= 4(4^k-3k-1)+9k\tag{rearrange}\\[0.5em]
&= 4(9\ell)+9k\tag{by the inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= 9(4\ell+k)\tag{factor out the $9$}\\[0.5em]
&= 9\eta\tag{$4\ell+k=\eta\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $P(k+1)$, completing the inductive proof.

This is all you really need to show.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $4^n -3n -1$ is divisible by $9$ for all positive $n$, ring a bell here? Induction.

The base case is obviously divisible by $9$. Assume that $f(k) = 4^k - 3k - 15$ is divisible by $9$ so that $f(k) = 9l$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Can you continue from there?

And since $Y$ is the set of multiples of $9$, $X \subset Y$... the result follows.

Comment: For showing that $4^n-3n-1$ is divisible by nine, is it enough to put some values in n and show that it's divisible by 9?

Comment: Not at all, you'd need to use induction. Show that it's true for $n=1$, assume it's true for $n=k$ and then show it's true for $n=k+1$.

Comment: @HGSur My answer handles the inductive part Zain just mentioned. With answers by Zain and me in hand, you *should* be able to see how they prove your claim. If not, please do elaborate on where you are struggling.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow, thanks for that. My induction was getting a little wonky, I'm getting rusty! :-)

Comment: Zain: props on mentioning induction as the real *key* to this problem. It seems like whoever gave this problem likely tried to hide that, but nice job highlighting the main part. :) +1

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow, Thanks you! Now I'm struck at the rearrange step :(

Comment: @HGSur The "rearrange" step--all that is going on there is realizing that you need to somehow use the *induction hypothesis* in your proof. What I did was simply stick the induction hypothesis in there after seeing that $4^{k+1}=4\cdot4^k$ and make right-hand side off-set whatever imbalance resulted because of the insertion of the induction assumption (if that makes any sense). Key point: make sure you tie in the induction hypothesis somewhere. That was the motivation for the rearrange part. In terms of equivalence, if you simply expand the right-hand side, you will see it equals the left one.

Comment: Finally got it! Thank you both for helping me! :)

Answer (score 2):

$$4^k-3k-1=(3+1)^n-3n-1\\ [\binom{n}{0}3^n!^0+\binom{n}{1}3^{n-1}1^0+...+\binom{n}{n-2}3^21^{n-2}+\binom{n}{n-1}3^11^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}3^01^{n} ]-3n-1=\\3
^n+n3^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{n-2}+...+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{2}+n*3+1-3n-1=\\3
^n+n3^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{n-2}+...+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{2}$$by factoring 9$$ 3
^n+n3^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{n-2}+...+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{2}=3^2(3
^{n-2}+n3^{n-3}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}3^{n-4}+...+\frac{n(n-1)}{2})=\\9k$$ so $$X=\left \{0,9,54,1008,..  \right \},Y=\left \{  0,9,18,27,36,45,54,63,...\right \}$$ hence X is subset of Y ,because Y contain all of $9k$ , but X contain some of $9k$